Conversion operator and bool operator for if init expression
Snippet
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

template <typename T>
struct W {
    operator T&() { return *t; }
    operator bool() const {
        std::cout << "called W bool operator\n";
        return t != nullptr;
    }

    T* t;
};

int main() {
    int x = 42;
    W<int> w{};
    w.t = &x;

    if (auto w_value = w) {
        std::cout << "w_value " << w_value << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "w is empty" << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

Code is here godboldt
What I want here is that in if (auto w_value = w) w should be contextually convertible to bool, such that the assignment works.
This works as expected if the line operator T&() { return *t; } will be commented out.
But when this line is enabled, the bool conversion operator will not be called.
Is there a way to make this code work, such that if w converts to true, then a reference to t will be assigned in the if-init expression?
I have c++20 at disposal.

This code doesn't make sense. If w is converted to bool, then w_value will also be a bool, not int& like you seem to want. Drop the assignment inside the if, eg: if (w) { int &i_value = w; std::cout << "w.value " << i_value << "\n"; }

Change the line to explicit operator T&() { return *t; }

@Eljay: the printed w_value is then 1 instead of 42.

What is the point of accessing w_value  instead of w directly?

Terminology: the code in question is not an assignment. It’s an initialization. You initialize objects when you create them. You assign to objects that already exist.

Ted has done a great job of explaining why operator bool() const isn't contextually called inside the if.
Other ways to overcome that

define a non-const overload
explicit operator bool() {
  std::cout << "called W bool non-const operator\n";
  return t != nullptr;
}


Use deduced-this from later C++ standard to define all the const, non-const, volatile, lvalue, and rvalue variations at once
template<typename Self>
explicit operator bool(this Self&& self) {
  std::cout << "called deduced-W bool operator\n";
  return self.t != nullptr;
}




the non-const overload does exactly what I need! Thank you!

if (auto w_value = w)

This makes w_value a W<int>. What needs to be done in order for if (auto w_value = w) to be valid one of the conversion operators must be used, so the compiler will try them out and weigh them against eachother. If both are equally valid, there is an ambiguity and the compilation will fail. If one conversion requires less changes than the other, that conversion wins.

operator bool() const - Makes a const_cast<const W<int>*>(this) to make the conversion operator match.
operator T&() - Needs not to add const to *this and is therefore chosen.

You can make operator T&() explicit if you'd like to favor operator bool() const, which is usually good anyway since it prohibilts accidental conversions. I'd make operator bool() const explicit too. operator bool() const would still be chosen in your example because of the bool context in which is in.
The only "downside" is that you'd need to be explicit about what conversion you want when you print w_value:
std::cout << "w_value " << static_cast<int>(w_value) << "\n";

... and that is a good thing.
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct W {
    explicit operator T&() {
        std::cout << "T&\n";
        return *t;
    }
    explicit operator bool() const {
        std::cout << "called W bool operator\n";
        return t != nullptr;
    }

    T* t;
};

int main() {
    int x = 42;
    W<int> w{};
    w.t = &x;

    if (auto w_value = w) {
        std::cout << "w_value " << static_cast<int>(w_value) << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cout << "w is empty\n";
    }
}


I do not think explicit cast is good in this case at all. Simpler and more flexible would be w_value.value() - you do not need to know template base type. Make explicit cast with explicit type would render this class useless.

@Slava There is no value() member function. The class only has two competing conversion operators and I aimed to answer how to deal with that particular case.

I mean to add that member that returns value or value reference. Casting especially with explicit type is counterproductive. For example how to output this into std::ostream in generic code?

@Slava Sure, one could add member functions to make it easier to be explicit, but I'm afraid that wouldn't mean much for the question at hand.  I wanted to restrict myself from adding design to OPs mre without making assumptions about what the code really looks like. Perhaps it already has other member functions that does these things? OP has narrowed it down fine and I'm happy to stay on what's being asked about.

Problem is - making that method explicit renders this class pretty much useless.

@Slava int foo{w}; etc. would still work, so explicit user defined conversion operators still has uses. I think the implicit conversion operators are cause for more problems than the explicit ones.

Whole purprose of this class as I understand is to make access to value simple. Explicit cast has uses, but in this case it does not make any sense. as It makes usage of this class convoluted, verbose and ugly. That is the point.

@Slava It is a POC class. We have our custom std::optional implementation, which has c++20 range support. You can access the optional value with a range based for loop and I was thinking to do something similar within if-init, since range-loop has no "else" branch.

@Slava Making the conversion operators explicit makes perfect sense because it prevents bugs and confusion. In OPs example, if the assignment w.t = &x; had not been made, the program would have resulted in dereferencing a null pointer. As it is now, it chose the true branch, but for the wrong reason.

@TedLyngmo then why not to use std::optional or similar implementation?

@TedLyngmo can you show how generic code printing this value to std::ostream would look like?

@Slava: https://godbolt.org/z/PjonohWTP is a way of almost doing the same as std::optional  does. Our custom optional implementation has direct value access forbidden. But with the help of clang-tidy and a restricted begin() iterator access, we come close to what we want.

@Slava Again, I am asking a question about why the program behaves the way it does and what to do about it - but without changing everything around it. If it was to be used in generic code, then one would first have to decide what conversion operator that should be used when printing ws value. Is it bool or is it T? Can T even be streamed? To expand on that I would say that W needs to make an operator<< overload and choose the right thing to print in there. Like this

@Slava ... or this to allow for non-printable Ts.

Re: "I am asking a question" - I meant I'm answering a question of course :-)

You can easily use std::optional with just one symbol added, but it makes code significantly safer:
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

int main() {
    std::optional<int> w; // = 42;

    if (auto w_value = w) {
        std::cout << "w_value " << *w_value << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "w is empty" << "\n";
    }
}

Live example
Unfortunately implicit typecasts are quite bad in C++ especially overloaded.

see my comment. We have our custom optional implementation.

This doesn't really answer the question though since std::optional doesn't have an operator T&() that could interfer. OP explicitly ask for how to make the code work with that operator.
